# Which files updated after composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have added a new package to my project via composer.
Now the project is on a shared hosting.
After uploading only the package from Vendor folder, 
The project not working.

What are the other files should I upload to my hosting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the composer autoloader then you should also update the vendor/composer folder and the vendor/autoload.php file.

The composer.lock file will also have changed but this shouldn't affect your application unless you're using composer on the server.